# jQuery Function operate when condition is correct OR event fires

Tags: jquery

How can I say something happens (function operates) in 2 condition?

For example when:

Checkbox is checked
OR
checkbox changes to checked

Example 2:

Whether dropdown selected option is equal to "x"
OR
checkbox selected option changed to "X"

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. Right now it sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: If you change an elements value via *code*, then an event doesn't fire, so you need to fire that event in code.  eg `$("#ddl").val("new value").change()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#mydropdown').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    var x = 'my_trigger_value';

    if (selectedOption === x) {
      dosomething();
    }
  });

 
  $('#my_trigger_value').change(function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if (isChecked) {
      dosomething();
    }
  });

  // Function to be called
  function dosomething() {
    
    console.log("Condition met (through dropdown OR through checkbox)!");
  }
});
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown and Checkbox Example</h2>

  <label for="mydropdown">Dropdown:</label>
  <select id="mydropdown">
    <option value="aaa">Option A</option>
    <option value="bbb">Option B</option>
    <option value="bbb">Option C</option>
    <option value="my_trigger_value">Option X</option>
  </select>

  <br><br>

  <label for="mycheckbox">my trigger value:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my_trigger_value" />
```

Comment: In your example, the "dosomething function" will operate just when the change event fires, I need the function to run whether the change event fires OR also when the condition is true without any change event! why do I need this?
for example, we use "dosomething" to hide the X element
in your model when users check the checkbox the X element will be hidden, and they submit the form and everything is fine
in next step
when they want to edit that submitted form and the form data will be retrieved, the X element is not hidden at the first load, because no changes haven't occurred yet